# How can I connect LabVIEW to MySQL MariaDB

Tags: odbc, mariadb, labview

We've just transitioned to using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) which uses the open source fork of MySQL, [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/).

I've always used MySQL and the corresponding ODBC connector.

Do I need to change my code to work with MariaDB and if so do NI recommend an ODBC for MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

There is [almost no difference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120178/whats-the-difference-between-mariadb-and-mysql) between (same versions of) MariaDB and MySQL. You should even be able to reuse the same connectors. 
However, you might want to use MariaDB's [own connectors](https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-odbc/), at least for new systems.

For the same reason, there should be no changes necessary for your LabVIEW code.